# Проверка переменных в методах, функциях, процедурах

Tags: php, c++, c, qt

Стоит ли валидировать входящие аргументы, если в вызываемом коде эти данные не меняются и жестко записаны, или например если полученные переменные(для аргументов метода) до этого вернул другой метод, который не может вернуть другого типа переменную или другой структуры?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под валидацией?

Comment: Вопрос на тему защитное программирование

Comment: Валидация на предмет корректности ожидаемой переменной

Comment: Из вас каждое слово вытрясать надо? Что значит "валидность"? Применительно к C/C++, например (раз в тегах стоят), проверить указатель на NULL - святое дело, независимо ни от какой "защитности".

Comment: Указатели это отдельная тема, а вот если это не указатель, а переменная, и как вариант в PHP.

Comment: Собственно может ли код выполнить не то что ему было сказано и на входе в функцию получатся не те аргументы что нужно или не те значения?

Comment: К примеру : Метод возвращает Int, я беру и пихаю его в другой метод, нужно ли мне в этом методе проверять на интежер к примеру ? Если допустим слабо-типизированный язык

Comment: На данный вопрос невозможно дать нормальный ответ, всё это слишком зависит от мнения, конкретной функции и языка. Я голосовал за закрытие данного вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Валидация аргументов зависит от того, о каком методе идёт речь.

Если речь идёт о *публичном* методе, то аргументы должны валидироваться, поскольку вы не можете гарантировать, что метод будет вызван правильно. Даже если на текущий момент все вызовы публичного метода правильны, нет гарантии, что никто не добавит невалидный вызовю

Если речь идёт о непубличном методе, то валидация — ваша добрая воля. Часто избыточная валидация *не нужна*, так как входящие аргументы всё равно проверяются в публичных методах. Однако если вы хотите зафиксировать внутренний инвариант класса, или вам кажется, что выполнение условия несамоочевидно из окружающего кода — можно вполне и добавить валидацию, это ваша добрая воля.

Разница происходит из того факта, что класс является фактически единицей инкапсуляции. Работая с классом, вы по идее должны держать в голове внутреннее устройство класса и его инварианты полностью. Если вам это не удаётся, возможно, класс слишком велик и имеет слишком много ответственостей. Если всё же нет, здесь вам и пригодится «внутренняя» валидация.

Comment: А что делать с функцей `sqrt`? Она должна проверять свои аргументы? Если да, то как? Обычный assert? Исключение? Code contracts? Как-то ещё? А если предусловия гласит, что она принимает только положительные числа, то может вообще никакой проверки внутри быть не должно? А может лучше использовать такие типы, которые вообще нельзя использовать неправильно? На эту тему можно говорить часами и не придти к какому-то правильному мнению. Потому что его нет - правильного мнения.

Comment: @ixSci: Для функции `sqrt` иметь предусловие контрпродуктивно, потому что для математического кода многие логические «условия» нарушаются в силу специфики вычислений с плавающей запятой. Например, 2(_a_ ² + _b_ ²) − (_a_ + _b_)² может оказаться отрицательным (пример есть у Кнута). Поэтому общепринятым решением является расширение домена до всех чисел, и возвращение `NaN` в проблемной ситуации.

Comment: @ixSci: Тем не менее, библиотека могла бы сделать выбор, нарушающий традицию, ничего плохого в этом нет. (1) assert не подходит, он лишь для внутреннего кода. assert означает «я уверен в этом условии, если это не так, пусть хоть крешнется», а вы не можете быть уверенным в вызывающем коде; (2) исключение — да, возможный вариант: (3) предусловия для публичных функций должны проверяться, т. к. вы не можете **обеспечить** их выполнение...

Comment: @ixSci: ... (4) да, специальный тип, совпадающий с доменом функции, был бы самым чистым решением, вот только система типов у популярных языков недостаточно богата, чтобы легко выразить все типы, и сделать автоматический вывод (иначе вам придётся делать это вручную, что не очень удобно).